# CI giving undefined variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I'm following examples online about retrieving data from models in CI. I've looked around here for an answer as my problem seems pretty easy, but every example I try still gives me **Message: Undefined Variable : updates** and **Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach**. Any Ideas?

**Model:**

```
function list_updates(){ 
    return this->db->get('updates')->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->model('updates_model');

    $data = array();
    $data['updates'] = $this->updates_model->list_updates(); // if i do print_r before render, the data displays in the view (but not formatted correctly)

    $this->_render('pages/publicfeed', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="message_count" style="margin-left:40%;">
    <?php 
        foreach ($updates as $up){
            echo $up->update;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: try to print_r($this->updates_model->list_updates()) and debug it

Answer (score 0):

In your view file, You didn't check where `$updates` have record or not. I think you are facing this issue when you don't have record. So just check before going through foreach lop.

CI `result()` function will return list of objects. So you can use count method to check for the record count.

```
<div id="message_count" style="margin-left:40%;">
    <?php 
       if(count($updates)>0)
       {
        foreach ($updates as $up){
            echo $up->update;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<p>No Records found</p>";
      }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data as array from query.

Change `result()` to `result_array()` in model. And `$up->update` to `$up['column_name']` where column_name is the name of the column in your table, for example `update_id`, `update_title`, etc...

This should do it.